# Should there be a "please provide all necessary source code" flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

I started reviewing a couple of weeks ago and am therefore very new to the process. A lot of the questions (might even be the majority) in the `Triage`and `First Post` section, that are presented to me, are ones that are actually about a valid topic but lacking any or most of the relevant code.
I was just wondering, why there is not tag for this situation, alike the "off-topic" and "too broad" ones.

Sometimes there already is a comment, basically saying "haz codez?" in various different politeness stages. I feel strongly, that a well prepared site (that also links to "How to ask") explaining the problem could also advise people, that they should have immaculate formatting, as this improves the odds of a good answer tremendously.

P.S.: I am very unsure about the tags here. Is (or "should it be") a feature request? I am actually just looking for some opinions and possibly a duplicate flag :-)

Comment: RE: PS: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me, and is certainly looking for more discussion than requesting a feature.

Comment: Flags are for when the post needs moderator attention. Missing code is not something a moderator can sort out. What do you want to happen when you use this "flag"?

Comment: Are these not sufficiently covered by the off-topic, no mcve close/flag reason?

Comment: @Don'tPanic What do you mean by "no mcve" flag? I am not aware of such a flag.

Comment: Flag->Close->Off-topic->Questions seeking debugging help (you have to read the entire close reason for the MCVE part)

Comment: @ChrisF Good question. I actually was expecting the "requires editing" button to work this way for the first couple of days. I thought it request editing by _the asker_. I then learned that it flags it for _moderator_ editing. In the end, it would be 'close' if no source gets provided. And thus could give better/more appropriate information then the MCVE article, esp. with the formatting.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the one that @AndréKool described.

Comment: Just flag it as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis "Requires Editing" is *only* for questions which can be edited by someone other than the OP to get the question into good shape and on-topic. Clicking on that sends the question to the "Help and Improvement" queue for other users to edit it. Anything that *requires* input/editing from the OP (e.g. missing information) is "Unsalvageable".

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis Code, a MCVE is *only required* for debugging questions (homework questions must show an attempt). Debugging questions are "why isn't my code working the way I want?" or "fix my code for me". No other question types *require* code. However, code usually helps greatly to narrow and clarify a question (i.e. without code, questions are often, but not always, "Too Broad" or "Unclear").

Answer (score 6):

Question askers first and foremost need to create content which is actually answerable. Leaving out critical content is often poorly received (with good reason).

No matter what the overall situation with closure is, users will find *something* to do about questions which they view are problematic. Sometimes, this means choosing a close reason which is perhaps not the best fit. As a result, these types of questions end up getting closed with several close fitting reasons.

In the case of no code, it really depends on the context. It is possible to ask questions without actually including code, so long as they are answerable without the code.

In the case where the code was required, but not included, I would generally ask in comments for the code to be edited in. This does work sometimes, but not that often. In the case it doesn't work, voting (or flagging) for closure as "unclear what you're asking" is appropriate in my opinion.

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

The debugging reason is also close, and mentions the MCVE, so many users will also go that route. I don't necessarily disagree, but do wish the wording was perhaps a little better because the close reason applies to more situations (lacking a reproducible or usable example) than just "debugging questions".

Comment: The whole formatting can be very confusing for newcomers. The link to an article that explains why the code is needed and how to format it would send a strong signal, that this 'fault' is recurring and that they are not the first ones to 'forget' the code.

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis: For questions with no code at all, you can link http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/.  Otherwise you can use `[mcve]` in a comment: it expands to a link on SO itself (but not here on meta).

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't know about the [mcve] macro.Thanks for that hint. I do not understand the relationship of SO and idownvotedbecau.se. Isn't that worse than having a dedicated flag for a specific and common situation?

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis: until / unless SO implements such flags or canned comments, linking an external site is the most convenient way to reduce repeated typing for these common flavours of low-quality question.

Comment: And I think it keeps the politeness level constant ;-)